# margin-left doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

In my code margin-left: is working only in the other browsers. In Firefox it seems I need to double every values i give to the margin-left: that works for the other browers. The element i need to marge is the blue circle.

If I inspect the element and change the css in the inspector and then i give margin-left: 60px (my margin-left: is normally 30px) it works. The same goes for 1em (is i put a 2em it works).

I just strated a formation so i'm not an expert, so if one of you can see where I've made a mistake, thanks in advance for telling me !

Here's my code

```css
.cercle-logo {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  color: #5CADD3;
  border: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cercle-logo:before {
  content: "";
  border: 5px solid white;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #5cadd3;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="cercle-logo"><i class="fa fa-chart-pie fa-2x"></i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browser use the parent padding as an offset for the absolute position child elements (chrome does this), because it's obvious that you will move the element using `left,right,top,bottom` not the **margins**

Say you have `padding-left:20px`, on the parent, and you set position absolute on one of it's children, if you won't see much changes, because some browsers uses that 20px and add it as an offset `left:20px`

One simple solution is to rest the offset, then use margins to push it, which i don't recommend you can use the `left` property to push it.

```css
.cercle-logo {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  color: #5CADD3;
  border: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cercle-logo:before {
  content: "";
  border: 5px solid white;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #5cadd3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3.7em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="cercle-logo"><i class="fa fa-chart-pie fa-2x"></i></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but I might have done something wrong because even though your explanation were clear, and the "code snippet" works well (I test it directly on Firefox), when i write is in Bracket and test it, it moves my blue circle totally on the left but this time on every browsers ...
Is there something I missed ?

Thank you for your time anyway !